# How to solve this real-analysis problem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis

[image]

Since $f(x)$ is bounded we have: $f(x) \le M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ Also, we have to prove:

$$\exists N\in \mathbb{N}\;\;\;\forall n>N\;\;\;:\;\;\;  \left| \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\cdot x^n   \right| < \epsilon$$

From the triangle inequality for integrals:

$$\left| \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\cdot x^n dx   \right| \le \int_{0}^{1} \left| f(x) \cdot x^n  \right| dx < \int_{0}^{1} M \cdot |x^n| dx = M\cdot \int_{0}^{1} |x^n| dx = \frac{M}{n+1}$$

So We have to find a $N$ so that: $\space\;$if $n > N$, then $\frac{M}{n+1} < \epsilon$

I just need a tad more help.

Comment: You're essentially done, although I would suggest $N$ instead of $\delta$ ($\delta$ is usually for a small positive real number, not a large natural number). You need to solve $\frac{M}{n+1} < \varepsilon$ for $n > N$. The left side is decreasing in $n$, so it's enough to solve $\frac{M}{N+1} < \varepsilon$. You can solve that with reciprocals: $\frac{N+1}{M} > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ so $N>\frac{M}{\varepsilon}$ is enough.

Comment: Why is $f$ bounded if it is Riemann integrable? For example $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$ for $x \in (0,1]$, $f(0) = 0$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I meant on $[a, b]$ Closed interval. Also @SimonS, for your example, $f(0) \ne 0$.

Comment: If $f$ is Riemann integrable, it doesn't have to be continuous.

Comment: @SimonS I believe it does. Perhaps I am wrong but I think you may be thinking about the Lebesgue integral for functions like $f(x) = 1$ if x rational, $f(x) = 0$ is $x$ irrational?

Comment: @SimonS, Note that function $f$ is Riemann integrable $\iff$ $f$ is bounded and the set of its discontinuity points has zero-measure

Comment: Ok, got it. Apologies for the diversion.